# Update anim references in script

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, sprite

For a 2D sidescrolling platformer, i've made a little gear system here is the description :

- Player (My main player gameObject with Gear script attached)

  - Gear (This gameObject is just for organization, it's named "root" in the script, and has no script attached)
  - Armor (the armor with sprite and Armor script)
  - Weapon (the weapon with sprite and Weapon script)

I have a script attached to Player which is Gear, with a reference to "Gear" GameObject to use it as parent transform for my future items.

In gear, I equip a weapon this way :

```c#
public void Equip(Wearable w){
        switch (w.type) {
        case Wearable.Type.WEAPON:
            GameObject weaponGO = Instantiate(w.gameObject);
            weaponGO.transform.SetParent(root.transform);
            Destroy (this.weapon.gameObject);
            this.weapon = w.GetComponent<Weapon>();
            break;
             //I did a swicth because i'll do it for armor, pets etc afterwards
        }
    }
```

The problem is that I also have an animator on the payer, to attack, move, etc...

SO when i change my weapon, it spawns at 0,0,0 and it's not following animations at all, and in my player's animations, I see"Weapon : Position (Missing !)", so i think this comes from animation references... But how to change this in my script?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the object naming. So after the instantiation you have to rename the new weapon object so that it's name would be exactly the same as the one you've deleted. The reference in the animator should update automatically after that.

Note that the position in the hierarchy should also be the same relative to the object with the Animator component.

Also note that the instantiated object should have the same properties (Components) used in Animator as the deleted one.

Comment: I tried and it resolved the missing problem but still, animations are not working at all (I have 2 sprites on weapon animation, and 4 on armor animation). the only solution I found is to keep the same GameObject but change all of its properties to the ones from the new weapon. In fact it doesn't solves the sprite problem, I always need to find a solution to avoid this animation sprite problem.

Comment: If the animation of this object has different sprites, you have to make some kind of abstraction. Maybe you should have a separate animator on the weapon object with a specific animation and from parent animation you would just call a method which plays this animation, using animation events for example. Edited the answer to reflect that.